# Having problem with "Show more / less" in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement the Show More/less with just CSS but it's not working as it should.

I was able to apply the toggle on the first div but when I click the on the Show More of a different div, it applies to the same first div and not that specific div.

```css
 /* Toggler styles */

    .mentor-info {
        position: relative;
    }

    [type="checkbox"] {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    label {
        /* display: block; */
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: top .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
    }

    label:before,
    label:after {
        position: absolute;
    }

    label:before {
        content: 'Show More';
        left: 5px;
        color: #008000;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]~ul {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: max-height .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked~ul {
        max-height: 300px;
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
        top: 100%;
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked +label:before {
        content: ' Show Less';
    }

    ul li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<main class="content-container">
            
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564584621/kobe_lq48jt.jpg" alt="">
                <strong><p>Kobe Bryant </p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id"> 
                        <label for="check_id"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bio: A 44-year old husband and father of 2.</li><br>
                        <li>Occupation: Retired professional basketball player</li><br>
                        <li>Expertise: 5 years</li><br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564584373/kiyosaki_ccrd22.jpg" alt="">
                <strong><p>Robert Kiyosaki</p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id"> 
                        <label for="check_id"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bio: A 53-year old husband and enthusiastic writer</li><br>
                        <li>Occupation: Professional Economist</li><br>
                        <li>Expertise: 5 years</li><br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564614348/lupita_hehsru.jpg" alt="">
                <strong><p>Lupita Nyo'ongo</p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id"> 
                        <label for="check_id"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bio: Born and raised in Kenya. She is now 30 years-old </li><br>
                        <li>Occupation: Professional Actress</li><br>
                        <li>Expertise: 5 years</li><br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to click on "Show more" of every div and toggle its relevent data.

Comment: Please close the main tag.. </main>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the id that is not letting it open i have chnaged it accordingly please check.

```css
/* Toggler styles */

    .mentor-info {
        position: relative;
    }

    [type="checkbox"] {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    label {
        /* display: block; */
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transition: top .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
    }

    label:before,
    label:after {
        position: absolute;
    }

    label:before {
        content: 'Show More';
        left: 5px;
        color: #008000;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]~ul {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: max-height .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked~ul {
        max-height: 300px;
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
        top: 100%;
    }

    [type="checkbox"]:checked +label:before {
        content: ' Show Less';
    }

    ul li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<main class="content-container">
            
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564584621/kobe_lq48jt.jpg" alt="">
                <strong><p>Kobe Bryant </p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id"> 
                        <label for="check_id"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bio: A 44-year old husband and father of 2.</li><br>
                        <li>Occupation: Retired professional basketball player</li><br>
                        <li>Expertise: 5 years</li><br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564584373/kiyosaki_ccrd22.jpg" alt="">
                <strong><p>Robert Kiyosaki</p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id1"> 
                        <label for="check_id1"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bio: A 53-year old husband and enthusiastic writer</li><br>
                        <li>Occupation: Professional Economist</li><br>
                        <li>Expertise: 5 years</li><br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mo1/image/upload/v1564614348/lupita_hehsru.jpg" alt="">
                <strong><p>Lupita Nyo'ongo</p></strong>
                <div class="mentor-info">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_id2"> 
                        <label for="check_id2"></label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bio: Born and raised in Kenya. She is now 30 years-old </li><br>
                        <li>Occupation: Professional Actress</li><br>
                        <li>Expertise: 5 years</li><br>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ID` is Unique, Change All `ID`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_id"> 
 <label for="check_id"></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="check_id1"> 
<label for="check_id1"></label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/b2htuesf/1/